# Problem to import native-base for react native

Tags: react-native, native-base

```
iOS Bundling failed 112ms
Unable to resolve module native-base from C:\Users\luizf\Bop\bop\App.tsx: native-base could not be found within the project or in these directories:        
  node_modules
  ..\..\node_modules
  2 |
  3 |
> 4 | import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';
    |                                     ^
  5 |
  6 | import { SingIn } from './src/screens/SignIn';
  7 |
```

can anyone help? thank you

I already installed react native

Comment: Did you install `native-base` as well?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?